# Invoke method whose parameter is bounded by an intersection type

Tags: java, generics

In the context of **static** methods, i'd like to **narrow** a type reference and invoke a more specific method for an object like this :

```
public static <T, L extends List<? extends T> & RandomAccess> void do(L list) {
    // Do some stuff
}

public static <T> void do(Iterable<? extends T> iterable) {
    if(iterable instanceof List && iterable instanceof RandomAccess)
        // invoke do(List&RandomAccess) method
    else
        // do something else
}
```

**So i'd like to know if there's a *syntax* allowing to call *do(Iterable)* rather that using some hack like this one :**

```
private static <L extends List<? extends T> & Comparable> L cast(Iterable<? extends T> iterable) {
    return (L) iterable;
}

public static <T> void do(Iterable<? extends T> iterable) {
    if(iterable instanceof List && iterable instanceof RandomAccess)
        do(cast(iterable));
    else
        // do something else
```

**NOTE :**
I know it isn't possible to cast my iterable this way

```
do((List<? extends T> & RandomAccess) iterable);
```

and it seams to me that the *erasure* of L in

```
L extends List<? extends T> & Comparable
```

is

```
List<? extends T>
```

So why can't i invoke the method this way ?

```
do((List<? extends T>) iterable); // Which results in invoking do(Iterable<? extends T)
```

Comment: the key word `do` is for loops

Comment: Of course ... it was just an example ...

Comment: It seems like `<T, L extends List<? extends T> & RandomAccess>` could be simplified to `<T, L extends List<T> & RandomAccess>` or `<L extends List<?> & RandomAccess>`, at least for these signatures.

Comment: @PaulBellora that's true, but doesn't respond either to the question

Comment: @AntoineMarques That's why it's a comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct: The erasure of intersections is the *first* type - ie `List` (for purposes of reflection etc).

You can get your code to compile without the "hack" by providing the intersection type to which to cast as a method type:

```
public static <T, L extends List<? extends T> & RandomAccess> void method(L list) {
    // do whatever
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // needed to suppress unsafe cast warning 
public static <T, L extends List<? extends T> & RandomAccess> void method(Iterable<? extends T> iterable) {
    if(iterable instanceof List && iterable instanceof RandomAccess)
        method((L)iterable); // calls the other method
    else
        return; // do whatever
}
```

This code compiles and the second method calls the first method, as desired.

There is no way to cast to an intersection without this technique.

---

Note that your code does not compile because `do` is a java keyword and thus is not a valid method name. I used `method()` instead to get a compilable example.

Also I think you meant `RandomAccess` where you coded `Comparable`.

Comment: I love simple solutions like in this case adding `L` to `method(Iterable..)` generic types. +1

Comment: I had thought to your solution in the first place, and discarded it because i didn't like this extra type parameter : it sounded like encapsulation break to me. Though, after reading your post, I must admit that this solution is short and pragmatic =)

Comment: That's done =) As i asked for a _syntax_ i think this answers the best =)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the erasure of `L extends List<? extends T> & RandomAccess` would be `List`, but even if I'm wrong, you couldn't use `(List<? extends T>) iterable` since that would not meet the requirements (a `List` is not necessarily `RandomAccess`). Thus, the only method that would match would be the `Iterable` version.

Edit: a quick reflection printout confirms my assumption. I named the methods `method` (creative, isn't it?) and get the following output:

```
... method(java.util.List)
... method(java.lang.Iterable)
```

You might now think that casting to `List` would be sufficient (and it might be, if you'd disable generics or call the method via reflection), but the compiler doesn't suffer from type erasure and thus knows that only `method(java.lang.Iterable)` matches.

Comment: As you guess in your edit, i had like to be able to invoke it using only the erasure. I find all this rather paradoxal, showing there's some missing feature in the language.

Comment: @AntoineMarques you're right. IMHO _erasure_ is the broken feature, or to put it the other way round, what's missing is true runtime generics. However, that's been left out for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to invoke erased version of a *static* method (in a clean build)

```
public static <L extends List<?> & RandomAccess> void do1(L list) {}

private static <L extends List<?> & RandomAccess> L cast(Iterable<?> iterable) 
{
    return (L) iterable;
}

public static void do2(Iterable<?> iterable)
{
    do1(cast(iterable));

    // try to invoke the erased version
    //do1((List)iterable);   // does not compile
}
```

We can invoke erased version of *instance* methods through raw type

```
static class Helper<T>
{
    <T, L extends List<? extends T> & RandomAccess> void do3(L list)
    {
        do1(list);
    }
}

public static void do2(Iterable<?> iterable)
{
    Helper helper = new Helper(); // raw type
    helper.do3((List) iterable);  // erased method
}
```

Back to *static* methods. Suppose we have this pre-Java5 code

```
#1 static void foo(List list){}

#2 foo(new ArrayList());
```

now after Java5, #1 is generified as

```
#1 static void foo(List<?> list){}
```

but #2 is kept as is, with raw type. How come #2 still compiles? The spec (15.12.2.2) makes it possible by allowing an unchecked conversion. The unchecked conversion can convert a raw `Foo` to `Foo<..>` (but no more sophistication like `Foo -> Foo<..>&Bar`).

The spec only contains enough tricks to make sure legacy code can survive typical generification. Your case is certainly not typical, and the tricks don't apply.